# MongoDB aggregation - Reduce array of string to object with key and value as number of occurrence of the string in the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

hope you are doing great.

I have some documents like this in mongoDB:

```
{_id:"someId", Fruits: ["mango", "orange", "mango", "orange", "orange", "apple"]
```

I want to use mongoDB aggregation to get this output:

```
{_id: "someId", Fruits: {mango: 2, orange: 3, apple: 1}
```

I tried a lot of way, and spent some times reading the docs but still can't figure out how to make it work.

Could you guys help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Fruits": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
          "input": { "$setUnion": ["$Fruits"] },
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "k": "$$m",
            "v": {
              "$size": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$Fruits",
                  "as": "d",
                  "cond": { "$eq": ["$$d", "$$m"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gRlpPPaA_Rv)

```
[
  {
    "Fruits": {
      "apple": 1,
      "mango": 2,
      "orange": 3
    },
    "_id": "someId"
  }
]
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much.